# Angular 9 + Springboot REST API social login OAUTH2

Tags: mysql, angular, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, angular-social-login

I am trying to understand how the google or FB social OAUTH2 login works if I want to mix Angular 9 as Frontend and Springboot as REST API backend. I am using MySQL DB.

What I understand this kind of logins do is:
1. a user logins through google for example in the web app (angular).
2. I get the user info in the backend (springboot) and I can work with it. Store in the DB, give permissions, etc.

I cannot find any course/video/tutorial/article doing this. Does anyone know about something that could help me?

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Google "angular springboot oauth2":
- https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angular. All of the logins are more or less the same.

Comment: @Tom thank you Tom, but it is not showing the social login, right? I am a little confused due to that fact. I am not finding the social login part. Thank you!!

Comment: Please If you get solution for this issue share it

Comment: Please refer this link https://www.javachinna.com/spring-boot-angular-10-user-registration-oauth2-social-login-part-1 @MohamadAlhamid

Comment: In this article( https://www.javachinna.com/spring-boot-angular-10-user-registration-oauth2-social-login-part-1 ) JWT token is used, I needed to used OAuth2 token, to generate token and it can not configurable in the service file.

Comment: @mikizas have you got the proper solution? If so, please share the details. I am looking for same. Thanks